# How is <tgmath.h> implemented?

Tags: c, overloading

C doesn't have (to the best of my knowledge) overloading or templates, right? So how can a set of type-agnostic functions with the same name exist in plain ol' C? The usual compile-time trickery would involve a whole bunch of macros, wouldn't it?

Comment: Why not just [read it](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#5ge3gHPB4K4/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.1.1.tar.gz|bZFm81g2I8w/glibc-2.1.1/math/tgmath.h)?

Comment: Michael Mrozek, because it is not available anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a great explanation of how it works in GCC [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131205042841/http://carolina.mff.cuni.cz/~trmac/blog/2005/the-ugliest-c-feature-tgmathh/).

Also, if anyone can solve the medium-difficulty exercise, I'd love to know the answer.

Comment: That was a great read. It makes sense that the whole thing is so kludgy, though a part of me was hoping for a magical "C with Templates" C99.

Comment: +1. Great article.  I'd love to hear the solution to the medium-difficulty exercise, too.

Comment: Spoiler for medium-difficulty exercise: Because it would produce the wrong answer for _Bool.