# How do math.h functions in C accept arguments of multiple types when overloading functions are not supported?

Tags: c, function, overloading, c99

For example, pow() takes double, float or long double arguments in C99. When overloading functions are not supported, how can this be implemented in a simple way?

Comment: There is [one function per argument type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.4). Where do you see overloaded functions?

Comment: You're mistaking, `pow` takes two double arguments.

Comment: If I understood the question, in the case of `pow`, `int` and similar are accepted using implicit conversions.

Comment: @rpsml: I do not think so. a `long double` argument to `pow` should generate a compiler warning.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, it should (depending on the flags) but it also compiles. And, if the long double is in a compatible numerical range, the code produces correct results. Not that I condone this practice. I am just stating the results.

Comment: @rpsml: The most important addition for the next release of the standard should be to enforce at least all common warnings by default.. If necessary, with allowance to disable selectively.

Comment: As mentioned, pow takes doubles as arguments and returns a double. In the case of Microsoft compilers, long double is treated as double, except for the old 16 bit compilers (those use an 80 bit long double).

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, it is a good question and the answer is not obvious.

Comment: @Olaf see 7.25 in C11 for the "overloaded" macros

Comment: Why did you tag this as C89 when it is a question about C99 ?

Comment: @M.M: Well, these are not overloaded (I assume that's why you put that into quotation marks), but they use the C11 `_Generic` feature. But this requires to know all types in the macro. Also OP is clearly talking about C99 and the type-generic macros are in `tgmath.h`, not `math.h` as claimed.

Comment: @Olaf The type-generic macros are in C99  (so they cannot rely on _Generic - or at least, they could not rely on it before C11)

Comment: @M.M: Oh, I just had a look into the current standard and as that is a perfect application for `_Generic` I was sure came with C11, as that is not possible in C99. A peek into the headers (Linux/gcc/glibc) proves me right:gcc builtins are used. Yet OP still did not clarify he is asking about `tgmath.h`

Answer (score 3):

By using a different name for each function, eg

```
float powf(float base, float exponent);
double pow(double base, double exponent);
long double powl(long double base, long double exponent);
```

In addition to this, type-generic math (`<tgmath.h>`, §7.25 in C11 and §7.22 in C99) defines some macros which do the dirty work without the need of function overloading. You can check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20131205042841/http://carolina.mff.cuni.cz/~trmac/blog/2005/the-ugliest-c-feature-tgmathh/) link from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726712/how-is-tgmath-h-implemented) answer to see the internals, but basically it reduces to checks like

```
sizeof (X) == sizeof (__real__ (X))
```

or

```
(__typeof__ (X))1.1 == 1
```

The example taken from the standard:

#### EXAMPLE With the declarations

```
#include <tgmath.h>
int n;
float f;
double d;
long double ld;
float complex fc;
double complex dc;
long double complex ldc;

exp(n) invokes exp(n) (function)
acosh(f) invokes acoshf(f)
sin(f) invokes sin(d) (function)
atan(ld) invokes atanl(ld)
// and so on
```

Comment: Note that `<tgmath.h>` actually requires compiler magic to implement in C99.  Since C11 `_Generic` was added which is capable of implementing the tgmath requirements.

Comment: `sizeof` is insufficient to detect the type. It might contain padding bytes, thus yield the same value e.g. for `double` and `long double` (they can have the representation, btw.). `__typeof__`, etc. are compiler extensions.

Answer (score 0):

With the below, the various types are "actual arguments"

```
// declaration
double pow(double a,  double b);

/// usage
pow(2.0, 3.0);
pow(2.0f, 3.0f);
pow(2.0L, 3.0L);
pow(2, 3);
```

In each case, the language itself converts these *actual arguments* to the *formal parameters* of the function.  In this case, to `double`.

So one one function `pow()`, no overloading.

Other similar yet different functions exist that take other parameters

```
float powf(float a,  float b);
```

Comment: I assume OP is asking about the `tgmath.h` macros